# object of the class could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
class int64(){
    var $h; var $l;
    function int64(){
        $this->$h=$h;
        $this->$l=$l;
    }
}

function int64copy($dst,$src){
    $dst.$h = $src.$h;
    $dst.$l = $src.$l;
}
```

While calling function `int64copy` its saying `Catchable Fatal Error: object of the class int64 could not be converted to string in line`

Any idea?

Comment: That error only seems to be a small symptom of an overall lack of understanding of objects and/or PHP syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use doc notation on objects - it's trying to concatenate the objects, so it calls int64::__toString() - which fails.

Edit: Better example:

```
class int64 {

    public $h; 
    public $l;

    function __construct($h, $l) {
        $this->h = $h;
        $this->l = $l;
    }


    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf('h: %s, l: %s', $this->h, $this->l);
    }

}

$a = new int64(1, 2);
$b = clone $a;

echo $a;
```

Comment: Using this, it says Cannot access empty property in same line at `$dst->$h`

Comment: where do i use that clone operator, don't mind - I am new here

Comment: In your class, replace `function int64(){` for `public function __construct($h, $l)` and when you instantiate the object pass values to `$h` and `$l`

Comment: That was because of the dollar signs. I have updated my example

Comment: @CraigMason You forgot removing dollar signs within the constructor.

Comment: @CraigMason, may i get your contact please? gtalk/skype?? my skype: pracasify and gtalk: pracasify@gmail.com please add

Comment: @CraigMason what about this type of recoverable error. See my question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338091/recoverable-error-object-of-class-could-not-be-converted-to-string-in-magento'.

Answer (score 0):

The notation to access properties is `$obj->prop`. That's a `->` not followed by a `$`. That used both inside of and outside of classes.

`.` is the string concatenation operator.

That plus some other minor fixes should give you:

```
class int64 {

    public $h,
           $l;

    public function int64(){
        $this->h = $h;
        $this->l = $l;
    }

}

function int64copy($dst, $src){
    $dst->h = $src->h;
    $dst->l = $src->l;
}
```

You'll still have a problem with the `$h` and `$l` variables inside `int64::int64()`. Where are those supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) : *Creating a copy of an object with fully replicated properties is not always the wanted behavior.*

```
class int64 {
    public $h;
    public $l;

    function __construct() {
    }
}

$src = new int64();
$src->h = "h";
$src->l = "l";

$dst = clone $src ;
echo $dst->h , " " , $dst->l ;
```